# Creating Text Files From a Loop

Tags: for-loop, fwrite, fclose, watson

I am using the Watson document conversion service. I have a set of .html files that I want to pass into the Watson API. I created two lists the first one (File_Name_List) contains the names of the .html files and the second (File_Name_List_TXT) contains the names of the .txt files I want the output of the Watson service to write to. Everytime I run the code below it gives me the following error: ValueError: I/O operation on closed file. I cannot figure out what the issue is - any help would be appreciated.

```
for file in File_Name_List:
for file_txt in File_Name_List_TXT:
    f = open(file_txt,'w')
    with open(join(dirname(__file__), file), 'r') as document: config = {'conversion_target': DocumentConversionV1.NORMALIZED_TEXT}
    f.write(str(document_conversion.convert_document(document=document, config=config, media_type='text/plain').content).lower())
    f.close()
```